# Nicer way to represent call differences in mocks, in pytest (or in general?)

Tags: python, pytest, python-mock

I'm having the issue that I'm using the `mock` library in python (2.7), and I see errors like this:

```
    def raise_from(value, from_value):
>       raise value
E       AssertionError: Expected call: run_sync(country_code='GB', email_data={'username': 'username-1n@n3m((', 'hotelier_name': 'Alexander QW*!@H#(!*@#', 'id': 'hotel-id-8nabqtQW', 'hotelier_email': 'alexander@rnwmenrqnweq#!@#.com', 'name': 'hotel-name-8nabqtQW'}, i18n_labels=<MagicMock name='elami_labels' id='140095030265936'>, mail_service=<MagicMock name='mock.mail_service.users().messages()' id='140095028784272'>, partner_id='partner-facebooking-@j344', partner_name='partner-name-ANQWWEnn', product=<Product object at 0x7f6a6ad1da50>, username='username-1n@n3m((')
E       Actual call: run_sync(country_code='GB', email_data={'username': 'username-1n@n3m((', 'hotelier_name': 'Alexander QW*!@H#(!*@#', 'id': 'hotel-id-8nabqtQW', 'hotelier_email': 'alexander@rnwmenrqnweq#!@#.com', 'name': 'hotel-name-8nabqtQW'}, i18n_labels=<MagicMock name='elami_labels' id='140095030265936'>, mailing_service=<MagicMock name='mock.mail_service.users().messages()' id='140095028784272'>, partner_id='partner-facebooking-@j344', partner_name='partner-name-ANQWWEnn', product=<Product object at 0x7f6a6ad1da50>, username='username-1n@n3m((')
```

This looks Ok here, because of the scrolling, but it looks a lot worse in the console. Like this:

> E       AssertionError: Expected call: run_sync(country_code='GB', email_data={'username': 'username-1n@n3m((', 'hotelier_name': 'Alexander QW*!@H#(!*@#', 'id': 'hotel-id-8nabqtQW', 'hotelier_email': 'alexander@rnwmenrqnweq#!@#.com', 'name': 'hotel-name-8nabqtQW'}, i18n_labels=, mail_service=, partner_id='partner-facebooking-@j344', partner_name='partner-name-ANQWWEnn', product=, username='username-1n@n3m((')
>
> E       Actual call: run_sync(country_code='GB', email_data={'username': 'username-1n@n3m((', 'hotelier_name': 'Alexander QW*!@H#(!*@#', 'id': 'hotel-id-8nabqtQW', 'hotelier_email': 'alexander@rnwmenrqnweq#!@#.com', 'name': 'hotel-name-8nabqtQW'}, i18n_labels=, mailing_service=, partner_id='partner-facebooking-@j344', partner_name='partner-name-ANQWWEnn', product=, username='username-1n@n3m((')

Even so, because the 2 lines are not aligned, it's hard to spot the differences.

Is there any tool that can fix this? I'm not good at pytest extensions, but probably if there is none, I should write one - if that's even possible. I'm sure a lot of people have this problem all the time.

Or perhaps there's some way, independent of py.test to show such a difference... a quick way to parse the calls and have that show up as our error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give [pytest-sugar](https://github.com/Frozenball/pytest-sugar) a try:

> a plugin for py.test that changes the default look and feel of py.test
>   (e.g. progressbar, show tests that fail instantly)

Seems like a step forward in having prettier output from `pytest`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the library. Does not do what I wanted unfortunately, even though it makes things prettier in general